# Problem with vim colorscheme st terminal

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, vim, colors, suckless-terminal

I'm using hybrid_material colorscheme for vim. When I open my terminal (st) and type st -e vim, my colorscheme doesn't preserve (I have everything in black). Here are some screenshots: [image: vim opened simply in terminal]

[image: Vim opened in st terminal with typing st -e vim]

Black vim is when Vim opened in st terminal with typing st -e vim and the other one is vim simply opened in the terminal

Here is my vimrc file: https://easyupload.io/ho0538

If someone could help I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be setting a special `$VIM` environment variable in your shell, but:

`-e COMMAND` is documented on the man page as

> suckless terminal executes `COMMAND` instead of the shell.

Now that simply means that anything you set in your shell's startup script (`~/.bashrc`, zprofile, whatever) isn't set. And that might very well include a `$VIM` that points to a folder with your vimrc and vim plugins/themes/tools.

Comment: Hm, alright... I got the same problem with termite terminal. The only terminal that shows everything correctly is xterm for me.

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: But the thing is that when i open vim in st typing st -e vim, all my vimrc binds are conserved. Only colors don't

Comment: ... you set `TERM` or some termcap-related environment variables in your shell init scripts, don't you? that's why "original" xterm still works – it's pretty much the fallback.